# Calculate the dimention of the Sierpinski Triangle written with the XOR method

Tags: c, xor, fractals

I have a code written with the XOR method for the Sierpinski Triangle. The data that it generates are the coordenates in x and y for the points that make up the triangle, which would be great if i needed to generate the triangle, but I dont. What i need is to calculate the dimention using the sandbox method .... so what i really need my code to generate is the mass of the triangle and its height. The mass really means the quantity of points that compose the triangle. So my question is, how do I incorporate into the code the ability to count the actual existing points in every line and not where they are.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ANCHURA 7

#define ALTURA 4

typedef unsigned char BOOL;

#define ON (BOOL)1
#define OFF (BOOL)0

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
BOOL spky[ALTURA][ANCHURA];
int i, j;

FILE*fout;
fout=fopen("xor.txt","w");

for(i=0;i<ALTURA;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<ANCHURA;j++)
    {
        spky[i][j]=OFF;
    }
}
spky[0][(ANCHURA-1)/2]=ON;

for(i=1;i<ALTURA;i++)
{
    for(j=1;j<ANCHURA-1;j++)
    {
        spky[i][j]=(spky[i-1][j-1]^spky[i-1][j+1]);
    }
}
long int total=0;
for(i=0;i<ALTURA;i++)
{
    for (j=0;j<ANCHURA;j++)
    {
        if(spky[i][j])
        total++;

    }
}
fprintf(fout,"%ld\t%d\n", total, i);
fclose(fout);
return (0);
}
```

Written in C in Code:Blocks

Comment: Just before the last nested loop where you write out the coordinates, create a new variable `long int total=0;` - and inside your loop replace the `fprintf` statement with `total++;` - when you exit the loop, do `printf("the total is %ld\n", total);` . Job done.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I did what you said and the result is that now the code generates the entire mass and the entire height of the triangle (which i added in). The problem is that I need the code to generate a list of numbers, not just the final. I need to generate a list of numbers that represent the number of points in a certain line plus the ones from the lines before. For example, for line 1 there's one point, for line 2 there are 2, but the mass of the entire section is 3 (2+1).

Comment: This sounds like a really basic programming problem. Do you understand how to implement a counter in C? You set it to zero before you use it, you increment it at the right time, then read it back when it should have reached the value.

Answer (score 0):

Change the last loop to:

```
long int total;
for(i=0;i<ALTURA;i++)
{
    total = 0;
    for (j=0;j<ANCHURA;j++)
    {
        if(spky[i][j]) {
            fprintf(fout,"%d\t%d\n",j,i);
            total++;
        }
    }
    fprintf(fout,"total number in this line = %d\n", total);
}
fclose(fout);
```

Now it sums up the number of points per line. If you want the center of mass, you can compute the moment of mass for each line:

```
long int total, all = 0;
double moment=0;
for(i=0;i<ALTURA;i++)
{
    total = 0;
    for (j=0;j<ANCHURA;j++)
    {
        if(spky[i][j]) {
            fprintf(fout,"%d\t%d\n",j,i);
            total++;
        }
    }
    moment += total * i;
    all += total;
    fprintf(fout,"total number in this line = %d\n", total);
}
printf("the center of gravity is at %lf\n", moment / all);
fclose(fout);
```